# Parse JSON with Swift

Tags: json, swift

I am facing some difficulties with parsing JSON - I have followed a tutorial for receiving data from SQL database. When I try to return and `Array` over to Swift it's ok, BUT I can't call any members of the `Array`.

**Swift:**

```
let myUrl = NSURL(string: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.Fr");
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

// Compose a query string
let postString = "Pseudo=\(PseudoVar)";

request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in

    if error != nil {
        println("error=\(error)")
        return
    }

    // You can print out response object
    println("response = \(response)")

    // Print out response body
    let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println("responseString = \(responseString)")

    //Let's convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:

    var err: NSError?
    var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error:&err) as? NSDictionary

    if let parseJSON = json {
        // Now we can access value of First Name by its key
        var firstNameValue = parseJSON["firstName"] as? String
        println("firstNameValue: \(firstNameValue)")
    }    
}   
task.resume()
```

**PHP (simplified):**

```
<?php
    array("Pseudo0" => "Hello", "Pseudo1" => "Good Morning");
    echo json_encode($returnValue);             
?>
```

Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your response is not `Dictionary` - it is an `Array`. But it can also a dictionary depending on server response. So you will have to put a check of either response is a dictionary or an Array. Your code should handle that, for example like this:

```
if let jsonArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error:&err) as? [NSDictionary] {
    for jsonDict in jsonArray {
        var firstNameValue = jsonDict["firstName"] as? String
        println("firstNameValue: \(firstNameValue)")
    }
} else if let jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error:&err) as? NSDictionary {
     var firstNameValue = jstonDict["firstName"] as? String
     println("firstNameValue: \(firstNameValue)")
}
```

Comment: my pleasure. This is just to avoid that error. In case server send a signle object or an array